# Loctite vs anti-sieze

Tags: steering, anti-seize

I just tightened the steering knuckle on the shaft of my brother-in-laws 2004 Ford Escape (apparently these are a design flaw).

Should I have used Loctite? Or anti-sieze?  Or nothing?

Is there a general rule to follow?

Comment: Welcome to the site ... which part of the steering knuckle are you referring to? There is more than one bolt involved, I'm sure? I'm just asking for clarity so we can get to answering your question :o)

Comment: Sorry @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 just saw this.   Yes, 2 bolts that connect the shaft to the steering column.  Accessible through the leg compartment through the firewall.  I'm glad I'm still young enough to crawl in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various grades of Loctite (and similar products). The one you'd need is the 'breakable' grade. It will protect the thread from rusting (which is one of the benefits of using an anti-sieze preparation) but can be undone without special tools if required. The Loctite 243 Medium Strength Threadlocker (colour-coded: blue) would probably be best. Don't forget to use Loctite Primer for predictable results.